# Get build result from jenkins rest api by xml path

Tags: jenkins, xpath

when I access `http://jenkins-url/job/argus_deploy_service/27/api/xml/?xpath=/freeStyleBuild/result`, I get `<result>SUCCESS</result>`.

Is there a way I can get `SUCCESS` directly?  I've tried `xpath=/freeStyleBuild/result/text` and `xpath=/freeStyleBuild/result/value`, but none with any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Text() function is [disabled](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16877) in Jenkins by security reasons from version 1.5.x.
You can get the content using sed for example:

```
curl http://jenkins-url/job/argus_deploy_service/27/api/xml/?xpath=/freeStyleBuild/result | sed -r 's/<[^>]+>//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `text()` ?

```
xpath=/freeStyleBuild/result/text()
```